# C# How to check a "binary number" for invalid numbers?

Tags: c#

Im currently sitting in front of one of my assigments and i have the following problem.
if i put in any binary number e.g. 11111111 it should check and output:  "Number 11111111 is a binary number".

But if it contains any other number except 0 and 1 e.g. 14111011 it should say:
"Number 14111011 is not a binary number". But as soon as it finds any 1 or 0 at any position in the string it automatically declares it a binary number.
Any advice would be very helpful.

```
           public static void OutputBinary(uint Binary)
    {
       string Check = Convert.ToString(Binary);
        for (int i= 0; i <Check.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Check[i] == '1' || Check[i] == '0')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is a binary number", Check);
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is not a binary number", Check); 
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {            
        Program.OutputBinary(14111101); 
    }
```

Comment: The code's doing exactly what you told it. This would be a good time for you to learn to use [the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/), so that you can step through the code and examine closely how it is evaluated the expressions you told it to evaluate. Hint: you can't possibly know that the number is valid until you've looked at _every_ digit, and yet the code you wrote includes its report on the legitimacy of the number _inside_ the loop, without anything to prevent it from doing so before the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a variable that will be true only if all digits of the string are either 1 o 0.

```
public static void OutputBinary(uint Binary)
{
    bool isBinary = true;
    string Check = Convert.ToString(Binary);
    for (int i= 0; i <Check.Length; i++)
    {
        isBinary = isBinary && (Check[i] == '1' || Check[i] == '0');
    }

    if (isBinary) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is a binary number", Check);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is not a binary number", Check);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either check the string

```
bool IsBinary(string text)
{
    return text.Any( x => x != '0' && x != '1' );
}
```

Or just attempt to convert it and catch the failure:

```
bool IsBinary(string text)
{
    try
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(text, 2);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Use the `break` keyword to bail out of your loop once you know it's not a binary number.  Then combine that with using a `bool` variable to tell you what happened.

This appears to be for schoolwork (as you stated), so I'm avoiding using LINQ for that sake.

```
bool isBinary = true;
for (int i= 0; i <Check.Length; i++)
{
   if (Check[i] != '1' && Check[i] != '0')
   {
       isBinary = false;
       break;
   }
}

if(isBinary)
{
     //print yes
}
else 
{
     //print no
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you are declaring the number binary or not binary for all iterations of the loop. Instead try.

```
bool isBinary = true;
for (int i= 0; i <Check.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Check[i] != '1' && Check[i] != '0')
            {
                isBinary = false;
            }
        }
if(isBinary == true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is a binary number", Check);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is not a binary number", Check); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, it is both basic and fast -

```
static void IsBinaryOrNot(int number)
{
    boolean isBinary = true;

    int copy = number;

    while (copy != 0)
    {
        int temp = copy%10;  

        if(temp > 1)
        {
            isBinary = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            copy = copy/10;    
        }
    }

    if (isBinary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number+" is a binary number");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number+" is not a binary number");
    }
}
```